# How can I get the value of a cell in the table to pass to a variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm a little frustrated because I can not get the value of the cell and save it in a php variable so I can then query the database.

```
<div class='card-body'>
    <div class='table-responsive'>
        <table class='table table-bordered' id='dataTable' width='100%' 
        cellspacing='0'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Host Name</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Cpu</th>
                <th>Mem</th>
                <th>Load</th>
                <th>Disk</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($results['results'][0]['series'] as $array) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo "<td>{$array['tags']['hostname']}</td>";
            foreach ($array['values'][0] as $value) {
                echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code produces a table with elements.
I wanted to get the name of the host when I clicked on a row and save a variable in php to be able to query a database.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi9ZZ.png

Summary:
I would like to be able to click on a hostname and save that value in a PHP variable to be able to use a database query in a WHERE clause, for example SELECT CPU, MEMORY FROM DATA WHERE HOSTNAME = VARIABLE_HOSTNAME.

VARIABLE_HOSTNAME would have the value of the row that you select.

Thank you very much everyone for your time and help.

Comment: PHP variables are stored on the server, you can't create another variable without creating a request to your server. If you don't want to refresh your page when sending a request, use `AJAX`, otherwise, use PHP's `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: Please, you can make a small example of how it would be.
By clicking on hostname I save the value in a php variable. Thank you. Forgive my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

On the higher-level, you can use AJAX for this problem.

Example steps:

1. add the hostname value as an attribute in the tr tag
2. add an event(click) for each row in the table. when clicked, get the attribute from the selected table row then use an AJAX to pass this value to the PHP.
3. use the passed hostname value in your DB query on the PHP

Example Code:

```
<table>

<tr data-hostname-value="Hostname value 1" onclick="saveHostname()">
  <td>Hostname value 1</td>
</tr>

<tr data-hostname-value="Hostname value 2" onclick="saveHostname()">
  <td>Hostname value 2</td>
</tr>


</table>

<script>
function saveHostname() {

  $('tr').on('click', function() {
    var hostnameVal = $(this).attr('data-hostname-value');

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      data: "&hostname=" + hostnameVal,
      url: PHP_URL,
      success: function(data) {
        // success JS code.
      }

    });
  })

 }


</script>
```

hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I can not do it. Try this but then when trying to read in php I do not achieve it with:

echo $ _POST ['txtlname'];

I have to say that the php and the script are in the same page.                                                   
            $('table tbody tr  td').on('click',function(){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    $("#txtfname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent);
    $("#txtlname").val($(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent);
});

Comment: Make sure that you are getting the value from the passed URL query data.

Comment: This is assuming the OP is using jQuery

Comment: @Dharman , yes you are right. I use it for the purpose of to explain the concept in simple ways.

Comment: Excuse me, I do not understand where you keep the value, that is, where the value is available, for example when closing the table:
.
.
.
</ table>
echo $ hostnale;

Comment: I need the $ hostname because when I click on a row I have to run a query to the database with the selected value, example:
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE HOST = & HOSTNAME